# Finding a string in a list and returning a secondary value with python

Tags: python

I am trying to find a way to search for a string in a list of values and return a secondary value if it is there. The ability to do a "close" match would be even better.

The list of values I will be using is decently large (200,000+ records) and has the construction of:

```
data1 -> number1
data2 -> number2
data3 -> number3
```

I will be using my string to compare with data1, and if it matches I would like to return number1.

The data can be manipulated in any way, as I have access to the raw data.

The strings I will be using for the search are user created and do not have consistency, hence why a "close" match would be very helpful.

An example of the data for the search vs actual would be as follows:

```
User value: ABC CO INC
Actual Value: ABC Company, INC

User value: Baker Company
Actual Value: Baker Company, INC
```

There will be larger inconsistencies, but those will most likely need to be manually edited regardless. I am just trying to lighten the workload of manual entries.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: the dictionary type is typically used for associating one object with another: `d = {"data1": "number1", "data2": "number2"}`. It's not going to give you "close enough" matching, though.

Comment: For "close enough" matching on dictionary keys, you can iterate through the keys explicitly making your check. When you find the best match key, get the value from the dict.

Comment: Very hard to help without some actual examples, what the data could look like. Is is (user generated) numeric data, or names, or natural language sentences?

Comment: An example would be similar to the following: Actual value: ABC Company, INC User value: ABC CO INC or Actual value: Baker Company, INC User value: Baker Company. There are much more dramatic inconsistencies, but those will most likely have to be manually fixed regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments say, a dictionary would be the best way to store the underlying data, and you will have to specify further what you mean by a 'close match'.

So you would store your data in a dictionary as follows (based on the example data in your question):

```
data = {
    "data1" : number1,
    "data2" : number2,
    "data3" : number3,
}
```

Say you have created some function which evaluates 'closeness' in this context, to your 'target' input

```
def closeness(string, target)
    ...
    return closeness_score
```

such that if string == target, the maximum closeness score is returned (say closeness is a percentage, it really depends on what you mean).

then you could use pythons 'sorted' function (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) to order the data by how 'close' it is:

```
by_closeness = sorted(data.keys(), key = lambda x: closeness(x, target), reverse = True)
```

Then your closest match would be

```
closest_match = by_closeness[0]
```

and you then just return the value

```
value = data[closest_match]
```

If you didn't have the requirement of this 'closeness' and were only looking for an exact match, you'd still use the dictionary idea, but just return the value:

```
value = data[target]
```

Which you could make more robust by using the dictionary 'get' method, which will return a default if target isn't present in the keys:

```
value = data.get(target, 'Target not found')
```

If it's simply some kind of string closeness you want, there are numerous measures for this, an example of which is the Levenstein distance (http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Levenshtein_distance).

Another key step in looking at the closeness would be to somehow normalise all the inputed strings, i.e. turn all to lower case, get rid of punctuation, etc.

From the examples you gave, in particular, it would probably be a good idea to replace common abbreviations, etc. i.e. CO --> company, Incorporated ---> INC, etc. If you eyeball your data you might be able to spot a lot of these.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing random access, a dictionary seems like a better choice, since it's based on a hash function, and will probably be more efficient:

```
d = {
  'data1': 'number1',
  'date2': 'number2'
}

num = d['data1']
```

If you need to iterate throughout the whole structure, you can retrieve the keys, and then retrieve each item like this, though it will definitely have a quite a bit of overhead, since a hash function will have to be applied to each item.

```
for key in d.keys():
    do_something(key, d[key])
```

---

If you will mostly be iterating through the whole structure, you could store them as a tuple list like this:

```
l = [
    ('data1', 'number1'),
    ('data2', 'number2')
]
```

You could iterate through the structure like this:

```
for data, number in l:
    do_something(data, number)
```

And you can have random access with a generator like this:

```
z = next(number for data, number in l if data == 'data1')
```

This will be less efficient for random access since you will have to traverse all te previous elements until the one you're looking for is found, but will be a lot faster if you will mostly be iterating